# Make Hero-Unit 100% width w/ Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get myself comfortable with Twitter BS.

Is there away to make the hero-unit 100% width of the browser, whilst containing the columns in a fixed width?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap `.hero-unit` in `.container-fluid` and `.row-fluid` (or don't even wrap in anything). "Fluid" in Bootstrap term means that in will take 100% width of the browser window. Wrap your other content in "fixed" `.container` and `.row`.

See how I've done this in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAy3g/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of Bootstrap 3, hero unit is renamed to `jumbotron`   http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron

> To make the jumbotron full width, and without rounded corners, place
>   it outside all .containers and instead add a .container within.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```